# SonarQube reporting stopped working after renaming maven artifact id

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I have a multi-module maven project that was running fine and was able to push data into SonarQube by means of running the mvn sonar:sonar goal.

Now somebody in my team has renamed to artifact id of the parent pom.

Now SonarQube thinks it's a new project (which I can agree with), but does not show any new reports after running the sonar plugin from maven.

I've been wondering if we can map this 'new' project to the 'old' project/report in sonar, so we can keep the project history

What I've tried is to set the project key in the parent module explicitly to

```
<sonar.projectKey>oldGroupId:oldArtifactId</sonar.projectKey>
```

But then Sonar complains "can't have 2 modules with the following key", which is probably because it tries to apply it to all submodules as well.

Has anybody tried this before or should I just throw away my old project and start over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to [update the project key](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Settings#ProjectSettings-UpdatingProjectKey). As described in the docs: Project Administration > Update Key

Comment: Thanks so much. I do not have the permissions to do that, but I'll ask the person who administers our SonarQube instance.